# setTimeout() inside setInterval() sequence fires off only once

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

Granted the following piece of code:

```
function updateOdometers(odometers) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        odometers[1].update(odometers[1].value + 10);
    }, 500);

}

setInterval(updateOdometers(odometers), 2000);
```

For whatever reason, this code updates the value of odometer only once, rather than every 2000ms with a delay inside. Googling/SO-ing around didn't get me much of a result. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837247/javascript-setinterval-only-running-once

Comment: Blah, didn't find the original question you're referring to.

Comment: @Bergi: this is a not very sane sanitized piece of code. I have a number of odometers I need to update. The update has to happen every 6 seconds and inner odometers need to update one by one. Makes sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line :

```
setInterval(updateOdometers(odometers), 2000);
```

should be

```
setInterval(function () {updateOdometers(odometers);}, 2000);
```

Otherwise you will be calling `updateOdometers(odometers)` and passing its result to `setInterval`.